# Access mongo shell from application

Tags: java, mongodb, shell

I am looking for the approach of integrating mongo shell in my application. Wondering whether how to achieve this. There might be two cases,

1. I created a file which contain mongo query. Also create a list that contain all the credentials of mongodb. The goal of my application is to automatically run the mongo query from the file to mongo shell. I am stuck at how to call and run mongo shell from application.
2. Or, is there any way to bind mongo shell interpreter in my application? As like https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb_terminal_online.php

My application is written in java .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can run mongo shell from your java application like this, assuming your mongo binary is correctly linked. But it would be way better to use the java driver instead, as other said.

You can find more about executing mongo query from command line here : 
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {

            // the query you want to run in mongo, you can get it 
            // from a file using a FileReader
            String query = "db.col.find();";

            // the database name you need to use
            String db = "database";

            // run a command from terminal. this line is equivalent to 
            // mongo database --eval "db.col.find()" 
            // it calls the mongo binary and execute the javascript you 
            // passed in eval parameter. It should work for both unix and 
            // windows 
            Process pr = rt.exec(new String[]{"mongo", db, "--eval", query});
            // read the output of the command
            InputStream in = pr.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                out.append(line);
            }

            // print the command and close outputstream reader
            System.out.println(out.toString());   
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks.. will test it.. using java driver for my scenario, i am finding it more complicated.. as the mongo query is written in external file and query is written in shell query.. my application need to read the shell query from file and execute.. So i am finding it difficult to convert shell query to java based query.. Do you have any suggestion regarding this scenario?

Comment: can you plz give little explanation about the parameter of this line: Process pr = rt.exec(new String[]{"mongo", db, "--eval", query});

Comment: @oxvoxic see my edit, let me know if it's not clear enough !

Answer (score 0):

You can do the things you want using [the Java MongoDB driver](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/java/).  This is the way MongoDB is intended to be accessed using Java and that is how I would do it.  While I'm sure you could find a way to access the shell from Java, it seems like a hack.

I would use the Java driver unless you have a compelling reason to do otherwise.  For your specific needs look at the [Eval function](https://api.mongodb.com/java/2.13/com/mongodb/DB.html#eval-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-).

Regarding your second example - I suspect that is just a web front end that is styled to look like a terminal instance.  It is probably using whatever server side language driver to execute the commands.

Comment: thanks for quick reply.. mentioned above comment @felix answer ,my application scenario which give me headache how to then use java driver